# Utf8_general_ci or utf8mb4 or...?

Tags: utf-8, localization, utf-16, utf-32, utf8mb4

utf16 or utf32?  I'm trying to store content in a lot of languages.  Some of the languages use double-wide fonts (for example, Japanese fonts are frequently twice as wide as English fonts).  I'm not sure which kind of database I should be using.  Any information about the differences between these four charsets...

Answer (score 43, accepted):

MySQL's `utf32` and `utf8mb4` (as well as standard UTF-8) can directly store any character specified by Unicode; the former is fixed size at 4 bytes per character whereas the latter is between 1 and 4 bytes per character.

`utf8mb3` and the original `utf8` can only store the first 65,536 codepoints, which will cover CJVK (Chinese, Japanese, Vietnam, Korean), and use 1 to 3 bytes per character.

`utf16` uses 2 bytes for the first 65,536 codepoints, and 4 bytes for everything else.

As for fonts, that's strictly a visual thing.

["The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)"](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

See also [MySQL documentation for Unicode support](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode.html).

Comment: Just to be extra-clear, the comment about `utf8_general` applies to all the other `utf8_*` collations too; all will be using MySQL's `utf8mb3` aka `utf8` charset.

Comment: @JohnFlatness Thanks.  Your comment is just what I was going to ask about next.  I thought that UTF-16 used 2 bytes for Mandarin characters, for example, though?  I'm looking at the documentation you gave me, hoping that it covers what 65,536 means. XD

Comment: Chinese characters are within the Basic Multilingual Plane (the first 65,536 codepoints).

Comment: It seems like the latter 2 are the better options, space-wise.

Comment: `utf8` and `utf8mb3` do not cover all CJK characters, some of which are 4-byte wide.

Answer (score 0):

> `utf8mb4` is the best.

`utf8mb4` supports 4 bytes per character compared to utf8's 3 bytes per character, so it covers a wider range of uses without error.

With `utf8mb4` you can support emojis, for example. If you try to insert an emoji in an unsupported character set you will get errors.

`utf8mb4` is the more modern version of the 2 and will replace the older version eventually.