# How can I change DB charset in Yii DB management system

Tags: php, mysql, yii

Can someone tell me how to set the DB charset from, let's say, utf-8 to latin2 or something like this?

Tried to google it but found nothing that could help...
Also, I tried [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/16/how-to-set-up-unicode/) method but for some reason this does not work for me...

P.S: I also tried to change it from main.php file under 'charset' which was default to utf-8 but it still does not work... I forgot to mention.

L.E: as you asked, this is the db setting:

```
'db' => array(
        'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname',
        'emulatePrepare' => true,
        'username' => 'user',
        'password' => 'pass',
        'charset' => 'latin2',
        'initSQLs'=>'SET NAMES latin2;'
        'tablePrefix' => '',
        //'enableParamLogging' => true,
        //'enableProfiling'=>true,
    ),
```

Any ideas? Thanks...

Comment: It would help tremendously if you could c&p the part of your config related to the database.

Comment: Have you tried `'initSQLs'=>'SET NAMES utf8 ;',` in your `db` array in `main.php`?

Comment: I have now, but it still does not work... I want to make it latin2 not utf-8. As I mentioned, it seams to default to utf-8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is 'charset=utf8mb4'

which would result in

```
'db' => array(
        'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname',
        'emulatePrepare' => true,
        'username' => 'user',
        'password' => 'pass',
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'initSQLs'=>'SET NAMES latin2;'
        'tablePrefix' => '',
        //'enableParamLogging' => true,
        //'enableProfiling'=>true,
    ),
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11533448/utf8-general-ci-or-utf8mb4-or most people go for latin2 instead of utf-8 since utf8 does not hold all the characters, with utf8mb4 (which is a better version of utf8, kinda like utf32) you have everything you need for latin2